# How to disable/pass refactoring preview window in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, refactoring

I'm using Android Studio for a long time and I always found annoying the fact that you have to manually move the mouse to click 'Do Refactor' when refactoring. Is there a way to do it by some keyboard shortcut or completely skip this preview window? When I'm refactoring I know what I'm doing and I don't feel like I need a preview in most cases.
I didn't find anything that could answer my question.

[image: Picture of the preview window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Android Studio. I couldn't find a way to disable preview, but I did find a keyboard shortcut workaround. Just press `Alt`+`D` and it will "do refactor".